# Menu Interface Player Records

Tags: python, menu

This has been answered. Move along. Thank you.

```
def players ():
    for i in range(0, n):
        name = raw_input("enter your name")
        speed = int(input("speed:"))
        accuracy = float(input("accuracy:"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that is missing in your code is the part that creates and maintains the list of players of each category. In your `players` function you should store them.

Then, you'd have a list of players and you could look at each of them to check whether they satisfy the condition `running_speed>running_min`.

Concretely, you need to define how to represent a player. It can be as simple as a `tuple` or a `class` (or a `NamedTuple`, or whatever). Then, after you query his characteristics, you can create a player object to store these characteristics that you can put in your list of players.

For instance:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, running_speed, passing_acc, shooting_acc):
        self.name = name
        self.running_speed = running_speed
        self.passing_acc = passing_acc
        self.shooting_acc = shooting_acc
```

Then:

```
list_of_players = []
def players():
    for i in range(0, n):
        name = raw_input("enter your name")
        running_speed = int(input("running speed:"))
        passing_acc = float(input("passing accuracy:"))
        shooting_acc = float(input("shooting accuracy:"))
        new_player = Player(name, running_speed, passing_acc, shooting_Acc)
        list_of_players.append(new_player)
```

And looking for them:

```
def sweepers():
    running_min = int(input("enter speed"))
    for player in list_of_players:
        if player.running_speed >= running_min:
            print(player.name)
```

It could also be a list comprehension:

```
sweepers = [player for player in players if player.running_speed >= running_min]
```

Comment: You can perform the "filter" using a list comprehension: `[p for p in players if p.running_speed > running_min]`